# how to import a table from a google doc to a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, google-docs

I am looking for a function similar to google sheet's built in function IMPORTHTML, where you can specify the index of a table in a html and then import the table in that html to a google sheet.  I was told that there is no such built-in function that imports a table in a google doc to a google sheet.  So, it must be done in a script.  I need a help to write such a script.

JD

ps.  The opposite direction is easy.  I can insert a link to a google sheet in a google doc.

Hi,

I try IMPORTHTML in a google sheet to retrieve a table from a google doc instead of a html but the importing doesn't happen.

I guess that I have to write a google script to make it happen.  I wonder if there is existing code somewhere so that I can just copy and use.  I guess the need should not be uncommon.  Even if google does not support this feature, somebody must have done this before in script code.  Thank you in advance for any guidance.

JD

Comment: About `I am looking for a function similar to google sheet's built in function IMPORTHTML`, in your expected situation, you want to achieve your goal using a custom function created by Google Apps Script?

Comment: Whether the to-be-developed script code is hidden in a custom function or in onOpen(e) function is not an issue to me.  Both should be fine.  Thanks, Tanaike.

Comment: I think I got example code that I can modify to fit my own need.  Thanks for everybody's attention to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to live import a table from Google Docs to Google Sheets with the IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML functions.

In both cases you have to publish the document:
`File` > `Share` > `Publish to web`

Then you can import the data with one of those functions:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://docs.google.com/document/..."; "table"; 0)
```

or...

```
=IMPORTXML("https://docs.google.com/document/...";"//tr")
```

*Note: I have encountered some technical issues with this method. For example, line breaks are added to texts unexpectedly and the content is not always updated in "real time".*